# PyGObject en Python 3.4 - ¿Cómo dejar un espacio en blanco entre widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interfaz-gráfica, gtk

me encuentro trabajando en un pequeño convertidor de unidades cómo mi primer proyecto de programación y estoy usando pyGObject (sin Glade) para crear la interfaz gráfica. Quiero crear un espacio en blanco entre los widgets page1_entry y page1_output, pero no se cómo hacerlo. El código es el siguiente:

```
 class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="PyConverter")
        self.set_border_width(3)

        #Add layout element notebook
        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)

        #Create notebook pages and insert a grid in each one
        self.page1 = Gtk.Grid()
        self.page1.set_border_width(10)
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label("Volume Units"))

        #Create page1 widgets
        page1_entry = Gtk.Entry()
        page1_entry.set_text("0")
        self.page1.add(page1_entry)

        page1_output = Gtk.Entry()
        page1_output.set_text("0")
        page1_output.set_editable(False)
        self.page1.attach(page1_output, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que estás usando un `Gtk.Grid` para distribuir los elementos, cada uno en una columna distinta, puedes utilizar la propiedad `column-spacing` del `Gtk.Grid`, cuyo valor puedes fijar llamando al método `set_column_spacing()`.

Tu código modificado quedaría así:

```
#Create notebook pages and insert a grid in each one
self.page1 = Gtk.Grid()
self.page1.set_border_width(10)
self.page1.set_column_spacing(12)
self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label("Volume Units"))
```

Puedes consultar las propiedades de GtkGrid en la documentación oficial de Gtk: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html

Otros recursos muy interesantes son el tutorial [«The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial»](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) y la [referencia de la API de PyGObject](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/).

Comment: He indicado concretamente 12 píxeles de espacio por seguir las recomendaciones de las [Guías de interfaz humana de GNOME](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/)

Comment: Alberto, muchas gracias, sí que me ha servido la solución. La verdad no tenía idea de que esa propiedad existía!